Staging Ground questions that have been "published" shouldn't show up as Staging Ground posts in the question list
When viewing my question list at / i'm getting this result:

There's literally no value in me being directed to a "posted" status staging ground post from the questions list given it's already been approved and posted and any action i may want to take would instead need to occur on the question itself that the staging ground post links to.
These should just be filtered out

Honestly questions currently in Staging Ground shouldn't be showing up in that list yet, either. It's for questions that have been posted to the site... and SG questions haven't been posted to the site yet.

eh, this was a feature i definitely like seeing, not because i personally care to see these posts, but because users who are looking for questions to answer are a good source to draw potential new curators from, and with the SG being so visible and full of searchable history in an easy to use interface, it'll be easy to review the reviewers. But i definitely think there should be an on-page toggle with memory that isn't just a custom filter.

I get there's value there, but at least with the current UI it's not clear that clicking on a SG question from the main page of questions will take you to a review queue rather than to a published, public question that can be asked.

@TylerH my (hopeful) guess is that they're showing up as a way of advertising the new functionality, and it isn't intended to work that way in the long term.

A fix has been deployed for this change. Thanks for reporting. Only questions with the New or Re-evaluate status should be displayed.
There will still be a small window where someone else visits the post before you causing it to post lock temporarily but we've reduced the cache time so refreshing the page should yield a different question.
